# Linear Regression Model

Tags: regression, linear-model

Which of the following is NOT a linear regression model?

```
A. y = w_0 + w_1 * x

B. y = w_0 + w_1 * (x^2)

C. y = w_0 + w_1 * log(x)

D. y = w_0 * w_1 + log(w_1) * x
```

Comment: please add 'self study' tag. it looks like a homework

Comment: "This question does not show any research effort" certainly applies here...

Answer (score 5):

When we say "linear regression" we mean linearity in *parameters*, not *variables*. Therefore, `A`, `B` and `C` are linear (the parameters $w_0$ and $w_1$ enter the equations linearly) while **`D`** is not (the parameter $w_1$ enters in logarithm).

See also [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regression_analysis) Wikipedia article, section "Linear regression".

Comment: If this is a self-study question, I know I should have not answered it directly. However, I saw an existing answer that I believe is wrong, so I thought it may be more important to give an alternative (and hopefully correct) answer right away.

Comment: I agree, d is not a linear regression

Comment: Polynomial regression is a special case of multivariate linear regression, so I must agree.

Comment: @d0rmLife, OK, it's good that we reached consensus.